# where can i find Jquery tabs webparts for Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: jquery

I'm after a Jquery tabs webparts for Sharepoint 2010?
    i came across this one
    http://jquerytabswebpart.codeplex.com/
But its only for SP 2007.
Any resources would be appreciated.
THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without jQuery, you can try the Easy Tabs:

http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/sharepoint-user-toolkit/Pages/Easy-Tabs-v5.aspx